# JavaScript Event Listener's Function Doesn't Work Outside Nested Loop

Tags: javascript

I work on a js project that has a nested loop and I've got into a weird situation:

When functions are in the nested loop, e.g.

```
window.onload = function() {
let board = document.getElementById('board');

for ( let i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
    for ( let j = 0; j < 9; j++ ) {
        const block = [];
        block[i, j] = document.createElement( 'img' );
        block[i, j].src = "empty-block.png";
        block[i, j].coordinate_i = i;
        block[i, j].coordinate_j = j;
        block[i, j].addEventListener('contextmenu', function r_click(event)
        {
            coordinate_i = event.target.coordinate_i;
            coordinate_j = event.target.coordinate_j;
            block[coordinate_i, coordinate_j].src="flag.png";
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        board.appendChild(block[i, j]);
        }
    }
}
```

code will work as expected and when the button will get clicked with right-click, the image will be replaced.

but when I move the function outside the loop and call it from the inside, e.g.

```
block[i, j].addEventListener('contextmenu', r_click);
```

the function won't work.

Can I get an explanation for these occurrences?

Comment: What are you trying to access by this `block[i, j]`?

Comment: Add the full related code (including the "loop")

Comment: this doesn't look like useful syntax: `block[i, j]` ... the comma operator means this should just be accessing `block[j]` always ... are you sure you've copied the code correctly here?

Comment: It should be `block[i][j]` if you are trying to access a nested array

Comment: Better use `this` or `event.target` to refer to the event target.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] of the code that does not work. That shows where e.g. `r_click` is defined in that code. And the error message (if any) that is shown in the console.

Comment: When I changed all of the `block[i, j]` statements to `block[i][j]`, the code doesn't work properly. Any suggestions about that?

Answer (score 1):

it does not work because the function r_click is defined inline. If you pull it out as a separate function, and bind both events using its name it will work.

This is inline definition notice that the name of the function is not required, because the function is not needed because the function exists in the handler.

```
 block[i, j].addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event)
        {
            coordinate_i = event.target.coordinate_i;
            coordinate_j = event.target.coordinate_j;
            block[coordinate_i, coordinate_j].src="flag.png";
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

This does the same as the code above, but the function is actually accessible from other places

```
    function r_click(event){
       coordinate_i = event.target.coordinate_i;
       coordinate_j = event.target.coordinate_j;
       block[coordinate_i, coordinate_j].src="flag.png";
       event.preventDefault();
    }
    window.onload = function() {
       //....code here ....
           block[i, j].addEventListener('contextmenu',r_click);
      //...more code here
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't work.  Code run as expected only when as is in the first example.

Comment: you are doing something really fuzzy with the code. I can't help you further unless you pose more information about the module